# Will adding Moq give my tests any added benefits

Tags: c#, nunit, moq

I understand using moq is great I havea database or list of some sort I want to mock but is it of any use for something like this.

My tests are passing but if using something like moq can make them easier to read or more maintainable I am all for it.

```
  [TestFixture]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [Test]
    public void encrypted_token_should_match()
    {
        var settings = new Encryptor2000.EncryptionSettings()
        {
            Secret = "1234"
        };

        var token = new Dictionary<string, object>()
        {
            {"1",1}
        };

        var hardcodedTokenValue = "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyIxIjoxfQ.wqrYm4ADb_P9qR2uCQh-VU6xX1KG6FwoCX9N2J0QpqCPPYm-4vchy7xmMtdzQ1xtBfryTP4ztJHohyb50CmjYA";

        var actualToken = new Encryptor2000(settings).Encrypt(token);
        Assert.AreEqual(hardcodedTokenValue, actualToken);





    }

    [Test]
    public void decrypted_token_should_match()
    {
        var settings = new Encryptor2000.EncryptionSettings()
        {
            Secret = "1234"
        };

        var token = new Dictionary<string, object>()
        {
            {"1",1}
        };

        var hardcodedTokenValue = "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyIxIjoxfQ.wqrYm4ADb_P9qR2uCQh-VU6xX1KG6FwoCX9N2J0QpqCPPYm-4vchy7xmMtdzQ1xtBfryTP4ztJHohyb50CmjYA";

        var actualToken = new Encryptor2000(settings).Decrypt(hardcodedTokenValue);
        Assert.AreEqual(token, actualToken);

    }
}


public class Encryptor2000 : IEncryptor<IDictionary<string, object>>
{
    private readonly EncryptionSettings _settings;

    public class EncryptionSettings
    {
        public string Secret { get; set; }

    }

    public Encryptor2000(EncryptionSettings settings)
    {
        _settings = settings;
    }

    public string Encrypt(IDictionary<string, object> token)
    {
        return JsonWebToken.Encode(token, _settings.Secret, JwtHashAlgorithm.HS512);
    }

    public IDictionary<string, object> Decrypt(string token)
    {
        return JsonWebToken.DecodeToObject(token, _settings.Secret, true) as IDictionary<string, object>;
    }

}

public interface IEncryptor<T>
{
    string Encrypt(T token);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Encryptor2000` doesn't rely on any *service* classes, so you wouldn't really have anything to mock. `EncryptionSettings` and `Dictionary<string, object>` are merely data structures, which easier to build than they would be to mock. So at this point, you'll find no value in using Moq.

However, let's suppose you have another class that may use your encryptor (or any other encryptor), and you want to unit test that class, independently of the `Encryptor2000`. In that case, Moq would make it easy for you to ensure that the class is calling the `Encrypt()` method with the appropriate values, and see what happens when that `Encrypt()` method returns various values. When you're injecting service interfaces into a class, that's where Moq comes in handy.

Comment: Thanks @StriplingWarrior your answer cleared things up